# How to make an item active(selected) by default while using Treelist(Ext.list.Tree) in Extjs 6?

Tags: extjs6, treelist

I want to make the first item from a tree list be selected by default. I am working on extjs 6. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am a beginner to extjs6 and was going through the kitchen sink examples here: [http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/examples/kitchensink/#tree-list]. I want to know how to make the "Home" as selected node (active) by default. i tried going through through the docs but was unable to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
listeners: {
    element: 'element',
    painted: function (treelistEl) {
        var treelist = treelistEl.component;
        treelist.setSelection(treelist.getStore().getRoot().firstChild);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is solution will work for tree panel but here a treelist is used. i need some solution to  set active for the Ext.list.Tree component.

Comment: Also works for treelists. Don't let the naming confuse you. I just edited my answer.

Comment: Still its not working. I am using ViewModel instead of tree store. this is my fiddle [ fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1n7i ]. Please let me know what i am doing worng.

Comment: You are right. The "treelist" is not a normal ext component. It extends from Ext.Widget, and it doesn't directly fire any events. I have edited my answer to reflect this. You should add this after line 89 in your fiddle. P.S. Also, you should get rid of the lines 33-36. Panels does not have a store config, and because of this your fiddle is generating some errors.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

In the listeners of the treelist:

```
painted: function (treelist) {
    var c = treelist.component;
    var model = c.getStore().getAt(0);
    c.setSelection(model);
}
```

That will trigger the selectionchange event on that same treelist.